# How to enable Chinese in Date.toLocaleString?

Tags: node.js

I have node.js installed on an Ubuntu server. When trying to call the following on a `Date` object:

```
date.toLocaleString("zh-CN", { year:"numeric", day:"numeric", month:"long"})
```

the above comes out in the US format. The exact call in a browser (Chrome or Edge) would return it as intended, for example:

> 2017年4月9日

Are all the globalization implementations available in the node.js installation that I installed via `apt-get`?

Comment: 2022: It works now, at least in v14.16.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js does not ship with full intl as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4689).

You can polyfill it with the [intl module](https://npmjs.org/intl) if you so wish.